# dojo cbtree identify branch

Tags: javascript, dojo, tree

I have created a cbtree I'd like to style using the label differently on a branch or root vs a leaf node. I can't seem to see any way to identify them or a add an attribute I could use to identify the branch or root.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After talking to the developer of the control there wasn't a way to identify them. He has added an expandable attribute with a true/false value that will allow me to style them using css.

cbtree 0.9.3-4 (Nov 2013)